# Showing that $e_k$ is an eigenvector

Tags: functional-analysis

Lev $V$ be the space $L^2[-\pi, \pi] $ with the inner product $$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) \overline {g(x)} \, dx$$For integers $k$, let $e_k(t)=e^{ikt}$. Consider the operator $K$ on $V$ by $$(Kf)(x)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi cos(x-t)f(t)dt$$ Show that each $e_k$ is an eigenvector for K and find the corresponding eigenvalues.

I started by writing the cosine in terms of exponentials. After a bit of elbow grease, I am nowhere near to proving the eigenvalue function $(Kf)(x)=\mu f(x)$ using the $e_k(t)$ above. How do I go about this?

Comment: What do you know about the Fourier transform / convolution? Also, do you know, that $(e_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ is an ONB for you $V$?

Comment: I know how to apply the fourier transformation. How does this help?

Comment: Basically the convolution rule would give you the answer below without calculating anything but $\mathcal F \cos = (0, \ldots, \frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}, 0, \ldots)$

Comment: @AlexR this is interesting. Can you show me how?

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\cos(x-t)=\frac{e^{i(x-t)}+e^{-i(x-t)}}{2}$. So
$$\begin{align} 
Ke_k(x) &= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{e^{i(x-t)}+e^{-i(x-t)}}{2} e^{ikt}dt \\
 &= \frac{e^{ix}}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(k-1)t}dt + \frac{e^{-ix}}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(k+1)t}dt
\end{align}$$

Now you can use that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{ilt} dt = 0$ if $l\in \mathbb{Z}^*$ and $2\pi$ if $l=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$${\cal F} Ke^{ik\cdot} = {\cal F}(\cos \ast e^{ik\cdot}) = {\cal F} \cos \cdot {\cal F} e^{ik\cdot} = \cal F \cos \cdot \delta_k$$
Inverse FT gives
$$K e^{ik\cdot} = \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} ({\cal F} \cos)_j \delta_k e^{ij\cdot} = ({\cal F} \cos)_k e^{ik\cdot}$$
q.e.d.

Comment: This is much better!

Comment: @User69127 Thanks, BTW if you desire, you can "unanswer" the first before a certain timespan elapses and set this as the answer. Not sure though.